# Removing NA's in tibble after using pivot_wider

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to create a table from a data set that takes two factors from a variable, pivots them wider, and lines them up in a single row. Unfortunately, I either keep producing two separate lists, or I get this:

```r
dput(head(test1, 5))

# Edited section:
test1 <- df %>%   # Code used to create the table below
  select(`Incident ID`,`Device Time`, Description, `Elapsed Time`) %>% 
  filter(Description == "CPR Stopped" | Description == "CPR Started") %>% 
  mutate(Index = c(1:16)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Description,
              values_from = c(`Elapsed Time`, `Device Time`)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(test1))

dput(head(test1, 5))

  `Incident ID` Index `Elapsed Time_CPR Started` `Elapsed Time_CPR Stopped` `Device Time_CPR Started` `Device Time_CPR Stopped`
  <chr>         <int> <time>                     <time>                     <time>                    <time>                   
1 F190158585        1 01'03"                        NA                      18'37"                       NA                    
2 F190158585        2    NA                      01'08"                        NA                     18'42"                   
3 F190158585        3 01'34"                        NA                      19'08"                       NA                    
4 F190158585        4    NA                      03'47"                        NA                     21'22"                   
5 F190158585        5 04'00"                        NA                      21'35"                       NA
```

I am trying to get a table that looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Index = c(1:3),
                 CPR_Started = c("00:01:00", "00:02:03", "00:05:46"),
                 CPR_Stopped = c("00:01:53", "00:04:30", "00:08:00"))
print(df)

  Index CPR_Started CPR_Stopped
1     1    00:01:00    00:01:53
2     2    00:02:03    00:04:30
3     3    00:05:46    00:08:00
```

Comment: What would be the expected output based on the 'test1' 5 rows?  Also, please show the code you tried

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) and a look at the original data it's hard to tell what you need.

Comment: Not clear whether 'Elapsed'  or 'Device' are used in the expected output

Comment: Hi all! I've added the code I tried using. Please let me know if I need to add anything else... Also, my apologies on the less than ideal reproducible example here.